# What were the demographics of New Orleans in the 1890s?

Tags: 19th-century, demography

What were the demographics of New Orleans in the 1890s? Population, race, born overseas vs born in the US, that sort of thing.

And what would be the best source to do more research about New Orleans in the 1890s?

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, @M.T. Black! What has your research shown you so far?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].
Thanks!  [Empire of Sin](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00K4C4HMQ/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1) has some information.

Comment: Total population of Orleans Parish c. 1890 was a little over 242k. That data and a lot more here: https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Orleans_Parish,_Louisiana_Genealogy

Comment: Hi Mark, I've mostly looked on google and wiki, but I've not found the exact information I'm after. Wiki says the population was about 240,000, but says nothing about demographics. I appreciate your help - thanks!

Comment: Hi Brian, thankyou very much for your helpful answer!